# How do I clip buffers to multiple lines/polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, clip

I have a map with 6000+ 1km buffers of ponds I want to clip them so the buffer does not cross a barrier which is a series of polylines in a separate shapefile.

I have created a 1 km buffer around all ponds.

I have merged several road files to create a barrier file.

I now want to clip the buffer rings against the buffers.

I tried converting the barrier lines to polygons and then clipping but this just clipped the edge of the whole shape not to the individual road features.

[image: Buffers]

[image: Barriers]

I basically do not want the buffers to cross a barrier.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please *edit* the question to contain not only what you *want* to accomplish, but what you have *done* toward accomplishing it. Piecemeal clips can be performed by use of Union, conditional encoding, and a Dissolve, or by iterating through the input with an Update DA cursor. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: can you show a zoomed in screen shot of just what you mean.  I dont understand if you are only talking about the edges or of every lines.  Also if it is the second case, and a line goes through a buffer, how do you know which side of the buffer to keep?